# Bluetooth headset compatible

Tags: bluetooth

I'm having some trouble getting a bluetooth headset working with a raspberry pi

I have read differents topics about these devices on the net, it seams there are a lot of problems with compatibility...

Which model of bluetooth headset can i buy ?

Comment: Have you looked at the list available verified peripheral list http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals?